# python script using dataproc gcp storage

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

Trying to submit pySpark script on gcp Dataproc. Below is the line of code causing the problem

```
With open("gs://movie_files_101/u.item") as f:
```

I'm getting an invalid file name or directory when submitting the job. In GCP I've created a cluster, storage bucket etc.

Comment: Can you please share more information and output: How are you submitting the job? What is the full output of the error? Also, can you post the output of `gsutil ls gs://movie_files_101/u.item` to confirm the file is correct?

Comment: The job is submitted as a pyspark job on a gcp cluster

Comment: Loading movie names...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/job-0724de41/original.py", line 50, in <module>
    nameDict = loadMovieNames()
  File "/tmp/job-0724de41/original.py", line 7, in loadMovieNames
    with open("gs://movie_files_101/u.item") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://movie_files_101/u.item'
20/05/02 14:11:20 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@1d4eb84c{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}

Comment: exa***@cloudshell:~ (empyrean-kit-27****)$ gsutil ls gs://movie_files_101/u.item
gs://movie_files_101/u.item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a Spark program you do not need to read the file using native python libraries.

You should use Spark Core/SQL libraries to read the data and create RDD/Dataframe from it, because your data might not fit into single machine.

```
df = spark.read.csv('gs://movie_files_101/u.item')
```

I'm assuming you are using Dataproc and dataproc has GCS Hadoop connector installed which makes `GCS` first class citizen in Spark ecosystem.

If you wish to still read the file using native python libraries you have following options.

The native python libraries do not understand the `gs://` file scheme.

**You can either read the file using `Google Cloud Storage Client Libraries` using following code snippet**

```
from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```

Code snippet is copied from : [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python)

You can read how to install the SDK from [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

**or you can do it old school way by copying the file on the machine and reading it from there. **

```
subprocess.run("gsutil", "cp" , "gs://movie_files_101/u.item", "/tmp/u.item")
With open("/tmp/u.item") as f:
```

Comment: excellent detailed answer have used some details you have highlighted here